# Консоль в Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Андроид студио только изучаю и интересует банальный вопрос, как в среде вывести какое то примитивное приложение в консоль? 
Например этот результат

```
public class variable {
public static void main(String args[]){
    int k;
    k = 10;
   System.out.println(k);}}
```

Comment: Зеленый треугольник слева от main метода

Comment: или воспользуйтесь классом Log

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно код в вопросе никак.

Система android не стартует с метода  `main()`, как в "большой" Java. Точка входа (`android.intent.action.LAUNCHER`) указывается в манифесте приложения (AndroidManifest.xml) и обычно это класс `Activity`.

Если надо что то вывести в консоль, то используется [класс `Log`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log).
Само приложение выполняется либо на реальном android-устройстве, либо в эмуляторе Android (изолированная виртуальная среда), а не на компьютере с IDE, поэтому консоль у нас на удаленном (отдельном) устройстве.

Создание [Hello World на Android](https://web.archive.org/web/20191203195029/http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru:80/android/android2.php) - в целом не тривиальная задача в несколько строк кода, а достаточно объемная работа

Comment: Все так, только метод main все таки есть в ZyogoteInit, и разработчик приложений не должен вмешиваться в его работу. Точка входа для него это конструктор `Activity` или `Service` описанного в `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: У меня не было цели так глубоко погружаться в особенности старта андроид-приложения, а лишь показать, что он принципиально отличается от классического java-приложения. Вы можете написать свой ответ, если считаете нужным что то добавить

Comment: @Максим, [main](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidInternals/article.html#internals) в данном случае служит для старта `os`, а не приложений. И ко всему, вопрос не про это, а как сделать лог приложения, любого, на что и ответил `pavlofff`. По этому и сказанное `не стартует с main` относится конкретно к приложениям, так как у них есть `Activity`.